# Scan for new hardware using a bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch installer that overrides my usb devices drivers.
how can I force my windows to scan for hardware changes using a batch file?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/1060172/365042

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
START /WAIT RunDll32.exe Syssetup.dll,UpdatePnpDeviceDrivers
```

Comment: Are you positive that the signature for the `UpdatePnpDeviceDrivers` function matches that [required by RunDll32](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787)? If not, [you'll quickly corrupt the stack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx). Don't make Windows clean up after you.

Comment: @CodyGray, I'm not sure... I just posted this as it is what I found online before when I needed to do this via batch file.  Please post a corrected version.

Answer (score 1):

1 The best way I found is:

```
powershell -windowstyle hidden -command "& {\"rescan\" | diskpart}"
```

For the detail, you can refer to [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415) :"Use the rescan command to rescan all I/O buses and cause any new disks that have been added to the computer to be discovered."

For Windows 2008/7 and above, the powershell and diskpart is shipped with OS.

Or just run it without powershell:

```
echo rescan | diskpart
```

2 The other way is use the MS command line tool, [Devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272), which you have to download it first

You can use it to do a lot of things, including enable/disable/rescan all kind of device(not only disk), update device driver, ... even on the remote machine.

You also can see the source code of it in [this link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/DevCon-Sample-4e95d71c)

Comment: I tried using `echo rescan | diskpart` to get Windows 7 to recognize a SATA SDD.  By recognize I mean I wanted the drive to show up in Device Manager->Disk Drives.  However, `echo rescan | diskpart` didn't do this.

Comment: Is the disk driver attached to your Windows 7?
And my answer is to rescan the drives within a bat
If you are using GUI, you can rescan it manually:
1. Right click your computer in the Device Manager, e.g. WIN-QQ2AVVMEOQ5
2. Choose "Scan for hardware changes"

Comment: `echo rescan | diskpart` works if I have the disk plugged in during startup, uninstall the disk, disconnect the SATA cable, reconnect the disk via the SATA cable, and then use `echo rescan | diskpart`.  If I start the computer w/o the disk connected, connect the disk via the SATA cable, and call `echo rescan | diskpart`, then the disk is not recognized.  I think it might have something to do with the SATA port not being activated/enabled at startup since nothing is connected at that time.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I suggest you to check the system/application/security event logs in the "Event Viewer".
If there is any error, it should be in these logs.
And please refer this this for more info about Event Viewer https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308427

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 ships with PnPUtil.exe. Run `pnputil.exe /scan-devices` from administrative command prompt.

https://serverfault.com/a/1060172/365042